# is it OK to kill bugs?

Tags: halacha, death, bugs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tzar Balay Chaim- Killing Flies?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1929/tzar-balay-chaim-killing-flies)

if someone has pests like mice or bugs. is it OK to kill them? why?